# How to download file from google drive using mvc?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using this code for download file from google drive with MVC.
In this sample using google web application instead of console application. 
Console application is working but in web application is not working.

```
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File Files = null;
byte[] fileBytes = null;
var service = GoogleAuthentication(CloudID);
FilesResource.GetRequest list = service.Files.Get(path);
Files = list.Execute();
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Files.DownloadUrl)) {
    fileBytes = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(Files.WebContentLink);
}
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);

return File(ms, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, pfile);
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File Files = null;
byte[] fileBytes = null;
var service = GoogleAuthentication(CloudID);
FilesResource.GetRequest list = service.Files.Get(path);
Files = list.Execute();
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Files.DownloadUrl)) {
    fileBytes = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(Files.WebContentLink);
}
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);

return File(ms, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, pfile);
```

Comment: define "not Working"  do you have an error message?

Comment: Why don't you use media downloader? Read more about it here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/media_download